# Removing the first character in a cell and duplicating it to an adjacent cell in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

The trouble is when I scan something with the barcode scanner, there is always weird first character. I'd like to remove it somehow automatically as I scan the barcode on google spreadsheets. I was thinking as it scans, an adjacent cell will copy the data minus the first character.

Any Ideas? How would I write the formula in the adjacent cell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might have been better to post this question on [Web Applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) but, assuming your data is in A2:

```
=mid(A2,2,len(A2))
```

and copied down to suit should work.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try this:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A1,".(.*)")
```

The first period, outside the capture group represents a single character of any kind, and the capture group catches everything after it